# Conditional scrollbar not working on chrome

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scrollbar, overflow

I am working on React js, and am trying to have a horizontal scrollbar which only appears when the window size is small. I have applied the following css styling on the parent div tag:

```
<div
      className="container"
      style={{
        minWidth: "100%",
        minHeight: "100vh",
        position: "absolute",
        overflowX: "scroll",
        backgroundColor: "#d3d3d3",
      }}
>
```

When I see the output on chrome browser, a horizontal scroll bar appears at the bottom.
But it is disabled and does not work at all.

Please help me with this!

Comment: You should use `overflowX: "auto"`. When you use `scroll` the browser always shows a scrollbar but with `auto` it is only shown when it is needed.

Comment: When I use auto, the scrollbar disappears and does not show up even when window size is small.